# Ant build for a project with tests

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have a project that I need to submit with a Ant build file. The project has two folders: one for the src and one for tests.  Would I be correct in assuming that I need to write two different build.xml files? One for the tests and a separate one for the source code. Or is it standard practice to have just one build file? I have never used Ant before ( as you may have guessed :))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a single Ant build file with separate targets for build and test.  [This example](http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/SampleAntBuildFile) is nicely documented and should help you out.